# How do I properly demolish a tub and shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, renovation, demolition

I'm planning to demolish my bathroom for a renovation, and not sure of the exact steps on demoing the tub and shower. Also worried about the shower since it's a large one piece. How I should go about that? Any tips or advice are appreciated. My house was built in the early 70s. I imagine I would need to cut the fiberglass one piece into pieces to get it out of the house.

Comment: what kind of shower, tile, tub and shower, stock vanity cabinet?

Comment: 1. Go bananas with a sledgehammer, like you see on all the HGTV shows.  2. ??????? 3. Profit

Comment: Before you go nuts on the demo, figure out where your water shutoffs are. There’s one where water enters the house and one on the street. Operate both to make sure they work. To attack the shower surround, get a crowbar/prybar under the edge and start peeling it back. To avoid hitting plumbing or electric, don’t cut too deep.

Comment: How old is the bathroom, if the bathroom is older than 1989 you should test various materials for asbestos.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger 1989 as a cutoff for asbestos containing products in a bathroom? That sounds awfully late to me. Shouldn't that date be much earlier?

Comment: @FreeMan you are right.  The materials still had it in the early 70s so probably safe after 1980 given people were still using up inventory.

Comment: The bathroom probably hasn't been renovated since the 1970s when it was built if I were guessing.

Comment: Excellent job, @JWr! This is now an answerable question. Please feel free to post the rest of your questions, each as its own question. Be sure to be specific about what you're after so we can provide specific answers. (So few people come back to edit their questions, this is really appreciated!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only tool you have is a hammer, beat on the tub & surround with the hammer until it cracks and breaks into manageable sized pieces. You may need the claw side of the hammer to help actually cut into the fiberglass. This will also help to release it from whatever backing is behind it (drywall, green board, cement board, plaster & lathe, whatever). Take the pieces out.

Of course, if your only tool is a hammer, you're going to have one heck of a job completing the renovation, so I'd suggest instead that you set your circular saw to about 1/2" cut depth and cut the tub & surround into manageable sized pieces. Once cut, you may need to use a pry bar to get the chunks off the wall (some of the backing wall will come with the fiberglass, some won't) and carry them out.

The 1/2" depth should more than go through the surround, but shouldn't go completely through whatever the wall backing material is. This will ensure you're not hitting wiring or plumbing behind the walls. You might consider a masonry type blade, depending on how your walls are constructed, as hitting cement board or even drywall screws/nails could easily destroy a regular wood blade. A cheap "demolition" blade (without carbide teeth) might be a good option.

In *either* case, wear a dust mask at a minimum - you don't want to breathe fiberglass dust - or choose a respirator rated for asbestos, since that was a common material in the 70s. You may want to have the walls tested for asbestos before you start, though. If you find that it's *not* there, you can breathe easier (literally) and have at. If you find it *is* there, you can take appropriate steps from there.

Comment: Don't forget the eye protection as those porcelain/steel/fiberglass tub shards could cut or blind you. A sawzall is another cutting tool you could buy, borrow or rent.

Comment: Ah, yes, @DAS - eye protection goes without saying, though I guess it really does need to be said. The OP was concerned about cutting through whatever is behind the walls - a Sawzall it rather a crude tool and is indiscriminate in what it cuts through - the circular saw can easily be set to only go so deep.

Comment: The posts are often read by others who may not completely think through all of the safety needs B4 jumping into a project, so I added my two cents. Indeed, a sawzall is more crude but it will get the job done if that's all you have.